# Problems integrating SWI-Prolog and C++

Tags: windows, c++builder, ffi, swi-prolog

I am trying to integrate Prolog and C++. I am using SWI-Prolog for Prolog and Embarcadero Rad Studio for C++. I want to take input in C++, process the input in Prolog and display the output in C++.

First it was giving "Unable to perform link" error, but after linking library of SWI-Prolog it gave the error:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES
(X86)\SWIPL\LIB\LIBSWIPL.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21
(possibly COFF)
```

I searched and find to resolve it using `implib.exe` and created a new library `newlibswipl.lib`.

After linking it in program it gives error as follows:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_PL_cut_query' referenced
from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_PL_new_term_ref'
referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_exception' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_fatal_error' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_chars_to_term' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_put_term' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_predicate' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_open_query' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_next_solution' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_get_arg' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_get_name_arity' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved
external '_PL_atom_chars' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD
STUDIO\PROJECTS\DEBUG\NEWPROLOG.OBJ [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to
perform link
```

C++ code:

```
// newprolog.cpp

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include "SWI-cpp.h"
#include "SWI-Prolog.h"
#include "SWI-Stream.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\lib\newlibswipl.lib");
using namespace std;

term_t a; 
term_t b;
term_t ans;
functor_t fun;

int main()
{
  int digit;
  cout << "\nPlease enter a digit to calculate it's Factorial.." << endl;
  cin >> digit;
  PlCall("consult(swi('C:\Program Files(x86)\swipl\swipl-win.rc'))"); 
  PlCall("consult('factorial.pl')");
  a = PL_new_term_ref();
  PL_put_integer(a, digit);
  b   = PL_new_term_ref();
  ans = PL_new_term_ref();
  fun = PL_new_functor(PL_new_atom("factorial"),2);
  PL_cons_functor(ans, fun, a, b);
  int fact;
  if(PL_call(ans, NULL)) {
    PL_get_integer(b, &fact);
    //int numb = fact;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And `factorial.pl`:

```
factorial(1, 1) :- !.
factorial(X, Fac) :-
  X > 1,
  Y is X - 1,
  factorial(Y, New_Fac),
  Fac is X * New_Fac.
```

Actually I have referred it from a youtube video in which the person has used QT creator instead of Rad Studio. The link is [Swi-Prolog with QT Creator C++ interface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-cHzbJMQ9k)
But I want to do it using Embarcadero Rad Studio.
So could anyone help me out Please..

Comment: I'm guessing that you try to use `LIBSWIPL.LIB` that was compiled with a different compiler.  This won't work, the compilers use different object formats. You must compile all the source of SWI-Prolog with C++Builder.

Comment: Sorry Friend I don't know how to compile all the source of SWI-Prolog with C++Builder. So can you help me how to do it ??

Comment: Not really. I suggest reading through SWI Prolog's documentation (especially build instructions) and see if it mentions a Borland C++ mode. If not then you have some work ahead of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
I got the solution to link the library of SWI-Prolog with Embarcadero Rad Studio.

Solution:

1. I used the `implib.exe` in command prompt to convert the SWI-Prolog library `libswipl.dll` to get the  COFF format library as the library was in the OMF format and the required format was COFF.
2. After getting the COFF version of the library of SWI-prolog, I copied it to the Embarcadero's Project Folder and included it in the Project.

This inclusion resolved the linking error and executed the Project.

Thank you to all for your suggestions..